# $ Is Undefined in Angular or document.getElementById() is Null

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using the following directive code to make tooltips in my Angular application:

```
//Creates a directive that is used to display tooltips throughout the application
app.directive('tooltip', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            $(element).hover(function(){
                // on mouseenter
                $(element).tooltip('show');
            }, function(){
                // on mouseleave
                $(element).tooltip('hide');
            });
        }
    };
});
```

The trouble is that I receive

> $ is not defined

in the console. Now, my take is that these are methods from jQuery. Since I have been trying to avoid using jQuery in this app (especially if it is only used for a tooltip), I decided to modify the code as follows:

```
//Creates a directive that is used to display tooltips throughout the application
app.directive('tooltip', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            document.getElementById(element).hover(function(){
                // on mouseenter
                document.getElementById(element).tooltip('show');
            }, function(){
                // on mouseleave
                document.getElementById(element).tooltip('hide');
            });
        }
    };
});
```

In the second case, the errors I receive state

> Cannot read property hover of Null

How could I clear the errors and avoid using jQuery. Is this possible?

**Edit:**

I have modified the code as follows to clear the errors:

```
//Creates a directive that is used to display tooltips throughout the application
app.directive('tooltip', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            element.on('mouseenter', function() {
                element.tooltip('show');
            });
            element.on('mouseleave', function() {
                element.tooltip('hide');
            });
        }
    };
});
```

However, now the `element.tooltip is not a function`. Is it possible to win here? :)

Comment: FYI, a DOM element doesn't have a `.hover()` method.  That's a jQuery method.

Comment: See the answer below for the `element` discussion. It is a jqLite object.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Angular Directive documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive), the `element` parameter is already a jqLite-wrapped object, so there is no need to call `$()` or `document.getElementById()` on it. You can perform operations directly on the `element` object.

Comment: What is this jqLite beast?

Comment: @MadPhysicist It's a lighter jQuery-like library that Angular includes by default. Check out this for more info: https://gist.github.com/esfand/9638882

Comment: See [AngularJS angular.element API Reference - jqLite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#angular-s-jqlite).